# Create a route out of router in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router, router

I'm using a vuetify application, App.vue looks like this

```
 <template>
  <v-app class="grey lighten-4">
    <nav>
      <Header/>
    </nav>
    <section><NavigationBar/></section>
    <v-content>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>
    <Footer/>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

This works perfectly. But I faced the situation, when I need to create an empty page, so I don't want load footer, header or bar. Is there any way to create a route for an empty page in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Nested Routes

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

```
 <template>
  <v-app class="grey lighten-4">
 <router-view>
    <nav>
      <Header/>
    </nav>
    <section><NavigationBar/></section>
    <v-content>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-content>
    <Footer/>
 <router-view>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: that looks very cool, thank you! But as I can see, this thing requires link changes too. For example if I have app/page1, app/page2 and I want to add app/newPage, there is no way. I need to do app/smth/page1, app/smth/page2 and app/newPage. Or am I wrong?

Comment: you can use  v-if="!$route.name === 'abc'"